# Store the view setting for File Explorer search results

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 I am able to set the default File Explorer view to "Details", and it persists as that view.

For File Explorer search results, however, I have found no way to make the view persist.

**Is it possible to persist File Explorer *search results* have "Details" view in Windows 10?**

Comment: Have you tried the _Save search_ capability to see if it retains your view within that format?

Comment: Weird, it persists for me.  Open a single Explorer instance, search for something, switch to View tab and switch to details.  Then close that explorer instance.  Open explorer, search again, it should be in detail view still, does that work for you?  The trick seems to be that if you move to another location (different drive, folder, etc.) and then perform a search it will won't be in Detail view until you repeat it for that folder.  Is that what you're experiencing as well?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You're exactly right. It keeps the setting for the specific folder but not for other folders. In previous versions of Windows it would be preserved across all folders. This is definitely not behavior that I want.

Comment: Here is a registry fix. [Search Results defaults to Content View in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-results-content-view-fix-details-windows-10/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the [comment](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-results-content-view-fix-details-windows-10/) from @w32sh, add the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}
```

Then, add the following DWORDs under that key:

```
"LogicalViewMode" = 1
"Mode"= 4
```

The results should pick up immediately by launching Windows Explorer and performing a search.

If that does not work for you, then delete (or, for safety until you've tested, rename) the following two keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

Comment: Can also copy/paste the registry text here into a .reg file and double click to push into the registry, worked for me:  https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-results-content-view-fix-details-windows-10/

Comment: @tbone Thanks. Just be careful when using .reg files without knowing what every line does. A single value can create a massive security hole on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2018: the CLSID

```
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}
```

must now be changed to

```
{36011842-DCCC-40FE-AA3D-6177EA401788}
```

Also, the keys needed should be formatted this way.

```
"LogicalViewMode" = dword:00000001
"Mode" = dword:00000004
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect. Both of those GUIDs are valid FolderTypes. One has not replaced the other. One is `Generic.SearchResults`, the other `Documemts.SearchResults`. To cover all the various SearchResults types, see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1498668/how-do-you-default-the-windows-10-explorer-view-to-details-when-looking-at-sea).

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot get this to work following the above instructions with {36011842-DCCC-40FE-AA3D-6177EA401788}. Any new fix?

Comment: This is not an Answer but really a new question. You can ask your question by posting it. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask