# Save the Explorer search result view settings (columns)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-search

This is a more in depth version of this question [Store the view setting for File Explorer search results](https://superuser.com/questions/1142521/store-the-view-setting-for-file-explorer-search-results)

I'm trying to save the column setting to instead of Folder show Path.

I do this 20 times a day...

[From Content to Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak7UF.png)

[Hide Folder, show Path column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbjE4.png)

Comment: Two answers:  (1) Go to a top level folder, set it, View, Folder Options, Apply to folders and OK out. This works decently well for a while.  (2) if serious, get xPlorer2 (zabkat) and it will save settings in a registry file. Do what you will, re-launch xPlorer2 and it will open according to settings - always

Comment: @John: **Apply to Folders** doesn't affect the **Search Results*** templates.

Comment: @KeithMiller correct, I've already tried that. I wish I could just program explorer somehow...

Comment: Consider a trial of xPlorer2 to see if it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to modify the Search Results view. Both involve registry editing. For either approach, you should know there are multiple Search Results templates:

```
gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes |
>> ?{(gp $_.PSPath).CanonicalName -match 'SearchResults'} |
>> select PSChildName, @{N='CanonicalName'; E={$_.GetValue('CanonicalName')}}

PSChildName                            CanonicalName
-----------                            -------------
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} Contacts.SearchResults
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} Documents.SearchResults
{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55} OtherUsers.SearchResults
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} Pictures.SearchResults
{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156} Communications.SearchResults
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D} UsersLibraries.SearchResults
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} Music.SearchResults
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943} Generic.SearchResults
{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010} PublishedItems.SearchResults
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b} UserFiles.SearchResults
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} Videos.SearchResults
```

Several of which most of us will never make use of. :D
But most likely, at a minimum, you'll want to modify **Generic** & **Documents** **Search Results**.
Since you want a Details view with modified column choices, I would recommend using an *AllFolders* entry, because this method allows you to copy the settings from an existing view.
Individual folder views are saved under:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

in arbitrarily numbered subkeys. These have possible subkeys of Shell, ComDlg, and ComDlgLegacy. These in turn have a GUID-named subkey, where the key name is a FolderType ID. So here is **Search Results in Documents** (after modifying view):
[image]
Export this key, then open the exported file for editing. Change the bag# to the sstring **AllFolders**, save and merge the modified file into the Registry.
[image]

And you would want to repeat this for each Search type.

The tricky part can be figuring out which bag # you want to copy. Searching by the FoldderType ID can quickly narrow things down. Procmon is another option. Or you can export (for later restoration) and then delete all the Bags subkeys and see which are re-created when you execute a search and set the view to your liking.