# How do you default the Windows 10 Explorer view to `Details` when looking at search results?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I do a search in Windows Explorer, it always defaults to the following useless view (ok, so useless to me anyway) called `Content`.

[image: I cannot and will not be able to see the path using the <code>Content</code> view.]

[image: Oh look I can resize the field with the <code>Details</code> view]

How does one make it always do Details view by default?

Comment: I try to make sure Windows Explorer view are always details. If the folder being searched shows details, then search (upper right search bar) results details as well. Results will vary but I can make it work for me as described above

Comment: @John So you have to apply this to every folder?  I don't understand; the screenshots above are search results.

Comment: Go to the top folder, set it the way you want (all settings) then View, Folder Options and "Apply to all folders"  You may need to do this a couple of times. Windows Explorer has its own mind

Comment: @John does it maybe apply recursively down from the folder you have selected?

Comment: Start at the top and the folder settings you selected apply to all folders below. That is why starting at the top folder how it is done

Comment: Still doesn’t fix the search results though.

Comment: I tried it here and using Windows Explorer Search (top right of Explorer) and not Windows Search produced a detailed list. It does put the folder type icon to the left and colors the search item but it is still the detailed list

Comment: A search view will be saved for a specific folder. but the default Search Results templates use Content view. I'll post a PowerShell script that creates custom templates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Edit 8/18/2022

Revisiting this answer with modified code that:

- Adds the Canonical Name as the `(Default)` value for each key to make further user modification easier.
- Clears existing saved SearchResults views to ensure the mew default is applied.
- Adds `IconSize` and `LogicalViewMode` values for users that may want a default other than `Details`. List of values aat end of post.

---

You need some registry entries that don't exist by default to set the various **SearchResults** templates to **Details** view. This modification can be applied machine-wide or per-user and the  registry entries can be created by merging a **.reg** file or kby **PowerShell** script.
The machine-wide PowerShell edit must be run from an Administrative PowerShell console. The .reg files can be saved with any text editor & then right-clicked & merged.

### Machine-wide PowerShell (Admin)

```
$FldrTypes = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
$hkcuBags  = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$hklmBags  = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'

gci $FldrTypes | gp | ? CanonicalName -match '\.SearchResults$' | %{
    New-Item ('{0}\AllFolders\Shell\{1}' -f $hklmBags , $_.PSChildName) -Force |
        Set-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)'     -Value (gp $_.PSPath).CanonicalName -PassThru |
        New-ItemProperty -Name Mode            -value 4  | 
        New-ItemProperty -Name IconSize        -value 16 |
        New-ItemProperty -Name LogicalViewMode -value 1  | Get-Item ### Dislpays key after creation
    $hkcuBags | gci | ? PSChildName -match '\d+' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -eq $_.PSChildName | Remove-Item
}
```

### Per-User PowerShell

```
$FldrTypes = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
$hkcuBags  = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'

gci $FldrTypes | gp | ? CanonicalName -match '\.SearchResults$' | %{
    New-Item ('{0}\AllFolders\Shell\{1}' -f $hkcuBags , $_.PSChildName) -Force |
        Set-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)' -Value (gp $_.PSPath).CanonicalName -PassThru |
        New-ItemProperty -Name Mode            -value 4  | 
        New-ItemProperty -Name IconSize        -value 16 |
        New-ItemProperty -Name LogicalViewMode -value 1  | Get-Item ### Dislpays key after creation
    $hkcuBags | gci | ? PSChildName -match '\d+' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -eq $_.PSChildName | Remove-Item
}
```

### Machine-Wide .reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec}]
@="Contacts.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}]
@="Documents.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55}]
@="OtherUsers.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
@="Pictures.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156}]
@="Communications.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D}]
@="UsersLibraries.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}]
@="Music.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
@="Generic.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010}]
@="PublishedItems.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b}]
@="UserFiles.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}]
@="Videos.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
```

Per-User .reg File

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec}]
@="Contacts.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}]
@="Documents.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55}]
@="OtherUsers.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
@="Pictures.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156}]
@="Communications.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D}]
@="UsersLibraries.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}]
@="Music.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
@="Generic.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010}]
@="PublishedItems.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b}]
@="UserFiles.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}]
@="Videos.SearchResults"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
```

What are all those different values?

```
gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes' |
>>    ?{(gp $_.PSPath).CanonicalName -match '\.S'} |
>>       select PSCHildname, @{N='Name';E={(gp $_.PSPath).CanonicalName}}                              
PSChildName                            Name
-----------                            ----
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} Contacts.SearchResults
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} Documents.SearchResults
{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55} OtherUsers.SearchResults
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} Pictures.SearchResults
{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156} Communications.SearchResults
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D} UsersLibraries.SearchResults
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} Music.SearchResults
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943} Generic.SearchResults
{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010} PublishedItems.SearchResults
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b} UserFiles.SearchResults
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} Videos.SearchResults
```

IconSize/LogicalViewMode/Mode/Vid values:

```
Name        LVM Mode Vid                                    IconSize
----        --- ---- ---                                    --------
Details     1   4    {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16      
Tiles       2   6    {65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3} 48      
SmIcons     3   1    {089000C0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16..31  
Icons(M-XL) 3   1    {0057D0E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 33..256 
List        4   3    {0E1FA5E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16      
Content     5   8    {30C2C434-0889-4C8D-985D-A9F71830B0A9} 32
```

---

Comment: Upvoted for the powershell script and list of folders at the end.  A couple suggestions: use full cmdlet names instead of aliases (see the Description at https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingCmdletAliases.md) and use .SearchResults in the match to avoid accidentally matching something unrelated that may be appear some day.

Comment: Thanks for this! May I assume that the '4' being applied to the 'Mode' key is what corresponds to a 'details' view? And if so, is there a list anywhere of other view modes that can be alternately applied? Would be useful to save off create multiple variations of these patches to set various options globally. Also, is there a listing anywhere translating these long hx valued class names into their corresponding windows views in English?

Comment: Yes to both questions. A list of how Mode (and other values) relate to icon mode as well as **PowerShell** code to genrate a list of FOlderType IDs & Names can be found in a detailed explantion of saved views that I'm working on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data/61240563#61240563 Take a look at that for starters.

Comment: Sorry for the german, I get `new-item : Der angeforderte Registrierungszugriff ist unzulässig... [and many more]` on Win 10 for the first command (machine wide)

Comment: Thanks, specifically for the global Search results view... Registry changes setting others have suggested *lose customization made to regular views*, e.g., adding *Frame Rate* column for *Videos*.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the feeedback.